# PCのChromeとiPhoneのSafariとで表示が異なる原因について

Tags: html, css, dom

入力フォームのfocusの位置が異なる件についての質問です。

Windows10のChromeでは入力フォームのfocusが画面上の一番上に表示されます。
iPhoneのSafariだと1つ下のフォームになっています。

調査したところ、どちらも一番上のフォームと二番目のフォーム、両方に`<input>`がautofocusに設定されていました。

なぜ、こういったずれが生じるのでしょうか。

Comment: 該当のHTMLやCSSやJavascriptなどをご提示できますか？もしできない場合は、再現性の取れる最低限のソースがあればより回答が付きやすいと思います。

Comment: 当初の質問時から調査結果追記しました。autofocusが複数のフォームに設定されていました。その場合通常は一番上のフォームが適応されるのかと思いますが、なぜsafariでは二番目が優先で適応されているのでしょうか。

Comment: おそらくは単なるwebkitとBlinkの実装の違いなんでしょうが、提示されているような状況は[仕様](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#autofocusing-a-form-control:-the-autofocus-attribute)で明記されている "There must not be two elements with the same nearest ancestor autofocus scoping root element that both have the autofocus attribute specified." に該当しそうですね

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> なぜ、こういったずれが生じるのでしょうか。

理由は、Safariのバグです。autofocusがついた要素がページ中に複数ある場合の動作はHTML仕様で定義されていて、先にDOMツリーに繋がった要素が優先されます。ChromeとFirefoxはそのように動作します。Safariは仕様に準拠しておらず、優先順位なくすべてのautofocus付き要素にフォーカスを設定するため、一番最後の要素にフォーカスが残ります。

対処方法は、1ページ中に複数のautofocusがついた要素を含めないことです。